# Bootstrap nested button groups with radiobutton behavior

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, buttongroup

Using Twitter Bootstrap, I have a button group with several sets of buttons. Some of these buttons have dropdowns. I would like this button group to have radiobutton-style behavior, as per [radio in bootstrap's JavaScript button section](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons). [Here's my JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m5Bp/) and corresponding code:

```
<div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" name="options">General</label>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <label data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
            <input type="radio" name="options">Users <span class="caret"></span>
        </label>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <label data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
            <input type="radio" name="options">Assignments <span class="caret"></span>
        </label>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <label data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
            <input type="radio" name="options">Other <span class="caret"></span>
        </label>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does Bootstrap have this capability?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/6m5Bp/1/

I embedded the option buttons in a drop-down `ul` menu....

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
 <label class="btn btn-primary">
  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option 1
 </label>
 <label class="btn btn-primary">
  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
 </label>
 <label class="btn btn-primary">
   <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="color:#fff;">More Options</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li><label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="options" id="option4"> Option 4</label></li>
      <li><label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="options" id="option5"> Option 5</label></li>
     </ul>
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: That's close, but not quite exact. I thing I've come up with a solution, though. I'll just add the behavior myself with $().button('toggle').